# Relation between electric charge and electric current distributions via velocity

Tags: electromagnetism, fluid-dynamics, electric-current, charge, continuum-mechanics

Assume we have a charge $\rho(\vec{r},t)$ and current $\vec{\jmath}(\vec{r},t)$ distributions given in some region of space. From Maxwell's equations we know that the only relation between these two distributions is the continuity equation $$\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} + \vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{\jmath} = 0.$$ Now, in standard fluid dynamics it is possible to define a velocity field $\vec{v}=\vec{\jmath}/\rho$ which corresponds to the Eulerian velocity of a mass density $\rho$. However, in electrodynamics, we can easily have $\rho = 0$ and $\vec{\jmath} \neq 0$ and, therefore, cannot infer the velocity $\vec{v}$ of charge density. Is this reasoning correct? If so, what did we additionally assume in fluid mechanics so that we could define $\vec{v}$ as above?

Comment: How can you have $\rho=0$ but $j\neq 0$?

Comment: @Deep: imagine a neutral current carrying wire.

Comment: You mean positive and negative charges cancelling out? In contrast mass comes only in one variety.

Comment: @Deep: exactly!